# React Native failed use axios post method to Zamzar API (https://developers.zamzar.com/) [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 422]

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, axios

Here my code:

```
const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('target_format', 'png');
  formData.append('source_file', '../assets/ok.jpg')

  console.log(formData);
```

function:

```
const startUpload = () => {
      axios.post(url, {formData}, {auth: {
        username: token,
        password: ''
      }}).then((res)=> {
        console.log(res);
      }).catch((err)=> console.log(err))
  }
```

[I get this use postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBIej.png)I wish I get same response in my App but I got this error:  [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 422]

Answer (score 0):

FormData value for a file is the object containing uri, type and name.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('source_file', {
  uri: '<path-to-file>',
  type: '<type-of-file>',
  name: '<name-of-file>,
});
```